# Search needs to be updated to work for jobs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Bringing jobs as a new tab on the site in general may bring confusion in regards to the global search box at the top.  It either needs to work for a job now or we need to explicitly state that the search does not work for jobs.

Newcomers or even people who have been here may do this:

[image]

To me the global search exists to handle anything on the main site so you may want to consider it.

Comment: Global search bar now explicitly states, "Search Q&A"; on prod now. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out! We'll explicitly state that the search works only for Q&A.

Answer (score 10):

I'd prefer that it does *not* search jobs. Things like "stack overflow" or "microsoft" shouldn't bring up job searches for the company. That would be polluting search research for both the Q&A side and the jobs side to have these intermingled.

Comment: that's fine but click on the jobs tab (if you have chosen the beta)..Once you are at the job tab the global search is still there...so it could be confusing that it is shown at the top but doesn't work.  I'm not asking to add this, it needs some rework or clarification from the team.

Comment: *shown at the top but doesn't work* - Except, it works perfectly. It searches for questions, which is the behavior **I** would expect. I can see how new users could be confused, but that's part of the basic functionality and I think they'd figure it out pretty easily

Answer (score 3):

The global search should remain as-is, IMO.

If you click on 'Tags', 'Users', or 'Badges', then use the global search box, it searches for questions. Do those need to be re-worked as well? I'd say not.

Plus, the first time you click on Jobs, it's pretty clear where you should type your search in.

The functionality all seems (to me) so self-explanatory, that once you use it once or twice, you'll have it figured out.

Maybe, change the hint in the search box from **search** to **search questions**, but even that seems unnecessary.

Comment: I think search questions as a watermark is good